# Looking for regex to find a sequence of characters

Tags: java, regex

I don't know a single bit about regex. I want to find certain occurences in my java project using eclipse. The words could be

- SEQ_NUM
- SEQNUM
- SEQNUMBER
- SEQ_NUMBER

searching strings based on word "seq" would generate lots of results. What regex should suffice my problem?

Comment: I can only recommend to learn some basics: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ It's an invaluable tool.

Comment: could you clarify your question a little bit more? what should be matched and what not? a search for "seq" would find everything that a regex search for "seq" would find.

Comment: If you went to the regular expressions tutorial it would take you one hour or less to learn enough to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to learn, but i don't have much time ATM to learn for a task which is not part of my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These four cases can be combined to the following regex:

```
SEQ_?NUM(BER)?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SEQ_?NUM(BER)?
```

- **SEQ**    - must exist
- **_?**    - '_' can appear 0 or 1 time
- **NUM**    - NUM must also exist
- **(BER)?** - 'BER' can appear 0 or 1 time

Answer (score -2):

This should work for you.

SEQ[_NUMBER]+

Comment: No. The part `[_NUMBER]` matches one of the following chars: `_`, `N`, `U`, `M`, `B`, `E`, `R`. The `+` will repeat the single char once or more. This means your regex will match things like: `SEQ_______` or `SEQNNNNNNNRRRRRRRR`, etc. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html